# MongoNetworkError: connection 5

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, discord, discord.py

Does anyone know what this problem might be?

`{ MongoNetworkError: connection 5 to magicalcreature-shard-00-00-jfi8q.mongodb.net:27017 closed`

when I run it on my pc everything's fine, everything's connected. But when I run thru heroku it gives me the error.The code on github is the same except I put process.env.MONGOD instead of the connection string. The connection string looks like this:

`mongodb+srv://AlwaysRejected:password@magicalcreature-jfi8q.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true`

Answer (score 0):

I came into this question while facing the same issue, and while its 4 months old, ill reply with what fixed it for me in case anyone else runs into the same issue.

The problem was that mongodb required a whitelist of ips, and since heroku doesn't use a static ip unless you configure an enterprise private space I had to whitelist all ips using 0.0.0.0/0